# Wordpress Theme modification display extra modules

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Thanks for viewing my question. I have a template which displays posts in a 3 by 3 block I am trying to extend it to 4 by 3 how would I accomplish this? I've managed to make it create an extra row at the bottom but I'm after an extra column

The code in questions is here:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">



<div class="row row-adj-gap">
<?php
$args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'post', 
            'posts_per_page' => 9
        );
query_posts( $args );

if ( have_posts() ):
    $lp_cntr = 0;
    while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    $lp_cntr++;
?>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="hvr-wobble-horizontal full-div">

            <a href="<?php get_date(); ?>" class="coverBox">
                <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">

                <span><i class="fa fa-braille" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php the_title(); ?></span>
            </a>
            <div class="desp-box">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <?php if($lp_cntr%3==0): ?>
</div>
<div class="row row-adj-gap">
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to:

- decrease block width by changing column sizes on post blocks (`col-sm-4`, `col-md-4`, and `col-lg-4` becomes `col-sm-3`, `col-md-3`, and `col-lg-3`) and
- increase post blocks per row by changing the row modulation (post-per-row) counter (`$lp_cntr%3==0` becomes `$lp_cntr%4==0`)

See the adjusted code below:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">



    <div class="row row-adj-gap">
    <?php
    $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post', 
                'posts_per_page' => 9
            );
    query_posts( $args );

    if ( have_posts() ):
        $lp_cntr = 0;
        while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();
        $lp_cntr++;
    ?>

        /* Change the following line to decrease block width: */
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <div class="hvr-wobble-horizontal full-div">

                <a href="<?php get_date(); ?>" class="coverBox">
                    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">

                    <span><i class="fa fa-braille" aria-hidden="true"></i><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                </a>
                <div class="desp-box">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


        /* Change the following line to increase posts in a row before a break: */
        <?php if($lp_cntr%4==0): ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-adj-gap">
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just change column class col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 in to

col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3